# How to create a filter bar in template? Django

Tags: django

I'm not asking for the html, but the django implementation. Within my model I have four categories for my car model: make, year, mileage and cost. The user can select multiple categories and it'll filter the results on the page.

Will the filter bar a form similar to a search bar?

I'm not sure how this would be implemented. Any ideas on how I can get started?

Comment: You can create a custom widget to display a form field as you like

Comment: @dentemm how would that actually work. I can send the form to the server, but how will I filter through the objects based on the categories chosen. I was thinking of having the choices inside a listbox and choose from there

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question right, but are you just looking on how to filter? I would just render a form that has dropdowns for all the possible choices within a category, and than filter using something like `Car.objects.filter(make=form.cleaned_data['make'],year=form.cleaned_data['year'],...etc)`